# Получить количество годов между двумя датами

Tags: javascript

Имея дату начала события и дату ее завершения, вычислить сколько полных лет продолжалось данное событие. Примечание. Отрицательные значения лет обозначают годы до нашей эры.

```js
let task07Btn = document.getElementById("task07Btn")
let task07Result = document.getElementById("task07Result")
task07Btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let firstdata = document.getElementById('dateFirst').value;
    let seconddata = document.getElementById('dateSecond').value;

    task07Result.innerHTML = `${(new Date(firstdata).getTime() - new Date(seconddata).getTime())/1000/60/60/24}`
})
```

```html
<table>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="date" id="dateFirst">
        <input type="date" id="dateSecond">
        <button id="task07Btn">Go</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="task07Result"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `let b = (new Date(firstdata).getTime() - new Date(seconddata).getTime())/(1000 * 3600 * 24)
    task07Result.innerHTML = `${s11}${Math.round(b / 365)}``
Можна так сделать, но думаю не очень правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом *getFullYear()* для объекта класса *Date* и отнять начальный  год эпохи UNIX, в данном случае JS.

Насколько мне известно, годы до н.э. встроенный календарь не даст установить.

```js
task07Btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var firstdata = document.getElementById('dateFirst').value;
    var seconddata = document.getElementById('dateSecond').value;
    if (firstdata<seconddata) {
        var fullyears = (-1970) + new Date(( new Date(seconddata) - new Date(firstdata) )).getFullYear() ;
        task07Result.innerHTML = fullyears;
    } else {
        alert('Некорректно выбрана дата.'); return false;
    }
})
```

```html
<table>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="date" id="dateFirst">
        <input type="date" id="dateSecond">
        <button id="task07Btn">Go</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="task07Result"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```